# Append xml param input to root node of target xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery, tibco, xalan

I have the source xml file as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:entry xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<ns0:content type="application/xml">
    <ns0:properties>
        <ns0:x>qwerty</ns0:x>
        <ns0:y>OREQ</ns0:y>
        <ns0:y>abc</ns0:y>
    </ns0:properties>
</ns0:content>
```

And my updated xslt file after Lingamurthy's reply looks as below

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> 
<xsl:param name="documentXML"/>
<xsl:variable name="temp" select="document($documentXML)"/>

<xsl:template match="ns0:entry">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$temp/ns0:entry/*" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
</xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The parameter above documentXML is passed as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:entry xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<ns0:link href="GetArtefactDetailsSet(ArtefactId)/EScHeaderSet" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/EScHeaderSet" title="application/atom+xml;type=feed" type="EScHeaderSet">
    <ns0:inline>
        <ns0:feed/>
    </ns0:inline>
</ns0:link>
</ns0:entry>
```

Note that all this process is being run in tibco and the isXMLDocument flag for documentXML parameter is true()

I am getting below error when running it 
   [javax.xml.transform.TransformerException] occurred during XSLT transformation: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.tibco.xml.xquery.ExprException: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:

I have been stuck in this for few days need to get this done desperately.
The resultant xml should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:entry xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<ns0:link href="GetArtefactDetailsSet(ArtefactId)/EScHeaderSet" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/EScHeaderSet" title="application/atom+xml;type=feed" type="EScHeaderSet">
    <ns0:inline>
        <ns0:feed/>
    </ns0:inline>
</ns0:link>
<ns0:content type="application/xml">
    <ns0:properties>
        <ns0:x>qwerty</ns0:x>
        <ns0:y>OREQ</ns0:y>
        <ns0:z>abc</ns0:z>
    </ns0:properties>
</ns0:content>
</ns0:entry>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with tibco but if the parameter you pass in is already treated as an XML document then I wouldn't call the `document` function on it, I would simply use it as in e.g. `$documentXML/entry`. Note however that the whole stylesheet looks odd to handle your input data as the Xml uses the Atom namespace but the XSLT nowhere takes that into account. Also the comma operator used is only available with an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the document can be passed as an xml document or xml string passing as a parameter using a isXMLDocument flag and i have tried it with and without `document()`, as per Lingamurthy's reply below i have updated the xml i'll edit it and update i'll remove the , notation as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing namespace declaration. Use the following XSLT, some corrections have been made:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:param name="documentXML"/>
<xsl:template match="ns0:entry">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$documentXML/ns0:entry/*" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but the above transformation with `<xsl:param name="documentXML" />` added to it also gave the same error

Comment: Looks like you are passing the document name as the param `documentXML`. I've edited my answer.. should help! Also, since the file name is being sent in the param `documentXML`, the `isXMLDocument` should be false

Comment: Now it's giving `The [javax.xml.transform.TransformerException] occurred during XSLT transformation:  javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.tibco.xml.xquery.ExprException: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ` so i think it parsed the document now

Comment: I hope you have copied the XSLT as it is from my answer(after it was edited), and you are passing the full file path of the second document in the param `documentXML` with `isXMLDocument` as `false()`

Comment: Hi, I had taken your latest xslt file and also i tried now with isXMLDocument as false(), still i am getting the error `he [javax.xml.transform.TransformerException] occurred during XSLT transformation:  javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.tibco.xml.xquery.ExprException: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ` followed by the passed parameter

Comment: I just re read ur comment above I am not passing file name but XML string just clarifying

Comment: @Raul, looks like we weren't in sync. I've updated my XSLT to get the document in the param `documentXML` and make use of it. Can you please try with `isXMLDocument` as `true()` and correcting your input XML(it doesn't have a proper closing `entry` tag)?

Comment: Hey it worked thanks a lot !!!! input xml was right already...Can you explain the difference between this and previous xslt of yours  , i overwrote it by mistake without taking backup apart from `document()` part

Comment: I had an assumption that you were passing the fileName of the external XML document.. document() function is used to create a node using fileName.. But, since you were passing the whole XML as string, you can directly use the parameter for further node processing, provided `isXMLDocument` is set to `true()'